# Find the Differential Equation (Integrating Factor Problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is #11 of Section 1.5 of the book [DEALA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136054250), 3E. So, we have only learned how to solve by using the integrating factor. BUT, there is a factor of 'y' on the right-hand side. What is going on?

> Find the differential:
>
> $x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 3xy$, y(1) = 0

Add: The solution I looked at after reviewing comments:

> $x\frac{dy}{dx} = 3xy - y$
>
> $x\frac{dy}{dx} = (3x - 1)y$
>
> $\frac{x}{3x-1}\frac{1}{dx} = \frac{y}{dy}$
>
> $\int\frac{3x-1}{x}dx = \int\frac{1}{y}dy$
>
> $\int3dx - \int\frac{1}{x}dx = \int\frac{1}{y}dy$
>
> $ln|y| = 3x - ln|x| + C$

But, the solution in the back is y is parallel to 0. I think it's a misprint.

Comment: This is also eqiuvalent to $xy'+(1-3x)y=0$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I see how to solve it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an integrating factor, it is variable seperable !
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \frac{dy}{dx}=(3x-1)y.
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be easy from here ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did not realize that. I have the solution now.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'x+y=3xy$$
observe that 
$$(xy)'=3xy$$
Integrate 
$$\int \frac {d(xy)}{xy}=\int 3 dx$$
$$\ln|xy|=3x+K$$
$$\ln|y|=3x+K-\ln|x|$$
$$y(x)=........$$